# WordPress MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

I have the following query:

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN postmeta
ON ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN postmeta AS mt1
ON ( posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN postmeta AS mt2
ON ( posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN postmeta AS mt3
ON ( posts.ID = mt3.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( ( ( postmeta.meta_key = 'event_start_date'
AND CAST(postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2019-08-18' ) 
AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'event_end_date'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) <= '2019-08-24' ) ) 
OR ( ( mt2.meta_key = 'event_end_date'
AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2019-08-24' ) 
AND ( mt3.meta_key = 'event_start_date'
AND CAST(mt3.meta_value AS DATE) <= '2019-08-18' ) ) )
AND posts.post_type = 'events'
AND (posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR posts.post_status = 'private')
AND ( ( posts.post_type IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','lodging','attractions','tracks','events','food','workshop','product','point_of_interest' ) )
OR posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','lodging','attractions','tracks','events','food','workshop','product','point_of_interest' ) )
GROUP BY posts.ID
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
```

All events have start date and end_date and could be set to end days after it starts.
The query searches for all event post type "event" that occurs between 2 dates.

My problem is that it takes 98 seconds to the query to fetch the data event though the table is quite small

How can i optimize the query for best results ?

Comment: Worry/check first if the query gives the correct result before optimizing as that is not how you should be using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in general..

Comment: Well The query gives the correct results

Comment: *"Well The query gives the correct results "* That can be pure luck with this query, did you read the manual then you understand why i said that... The query can only really be valid on MySQL 5.7.5 + with enabled sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to do [functional dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: Futher more questions about performance should also include `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the query/question.. And a `EXPLAIN query` output.. And maybe in because the GROUP BY seams the used wrong also a example data and expected result .. see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: But in general i think you are better off with something like `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE ... END)) as post_id, [, ...] FROM ...  GROUP BY posts.ID` or `SELECT SUM(CASE ... END)) as post_id, [, ...] FROM ...  GROUP BY posts.ID`  to convert records to columns instead of self joining alot..  (Re)search "MySQL pivot" on this website then you will understand it better..

Comment: Anytime you use a function (and you use four), things are potentially slower than they might otherwise have been. Every time you use a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions, a kitten dies.

Comment: Note for instance, whether you cast it as a date or not, '2019-08-18' is 'larger' than '2019-07-19'

Comment: Also, I'm really struggling to understand the logic of `( p.post_type IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','lodging','attractions','tracks','events','food','workshop','product','point_of_interest' ) 
    OR p.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','lodging','attractions','tracks','events','food','workshop','product','point_of_interest' )`

Comment: This was asked for 2 hours ago, but you haven't added it. When you ask for query optimization help, you should post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for each table, and also the result of `EXPLAIN ...` for the query you are trying to optimize. Please help us help you! Don't make us guess at the indexes you might have in your table!